# Change color for character in specific position

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have table in MS Word (2016) with 1 to 7 digit numbers (from ones to millions), I need that all ones, thousands and millions would be in green color, tens, ten thousands - in blue and hundreds and hundred thousands - in red. 
Can you please help me with vba script for this?

```
Sub creatable()

Dim docNew As Document
Dim tableNew As Table
Dim celltable As Cell

Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim Rndm As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
 Dim celTable As Cell
 Dim intCount As Integer
 Dim intChar As Integer


a = CInt((Rnd() + 1) * (Int((2025 * Rnd()) + 1)))
b = CInt((Rnd() + 1) * (Int((4355 * Rnd()) + 1)))
Rndm = a + b

Set docNew = Documents.Add
Set tableNew = docNew.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 6, 12)

For y = 1 To 12
With tableNew
  .Cell(X, y).Range.InsertAfter Rndm * X
  End With
 For X = 1 To 6
  With tableNew
  .Cell(X, y).Range.InsertAfter Rndm * y
  End With
Next
Next

 For Each celTable In tableNew.Range.Cells
 intChar = celTable.Range.Characters.Count
If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 1 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 2 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 3 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 4 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 5 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 6 Then
celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 6).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 End If
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 7 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 6).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 7).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 End If

 intCount = intCount + 1

 Next celTable

End Sub
```

[This is how it should look at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCYdR.png)
[image]

Comment: What kind of research have you done? Please provide the code you've tried and explain how it doesn't work. Note that StackOverflow is not a tutorial or code-writing service, as described in the [help].

Comment: I have a table and random value in it. I can count length for each number, but don't know, how to set color properly:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found (not perfect, but at least works):

```
Sub creatable()

Dim docNew As Document
Dim tableNew As Table
Dim celltable As Cell

Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim Rndm As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
 Dim celTable As Cell
 Dim intCount As Integer
 Dim intChar As Integer


a = CInt((Rnd() + 1) * (Int((2025 * Rnd()) + 1)))
b = CInt((Rnd() + 1) * (Int((4355 * Rnd()) + 1)))
Rndm = a + b

Set docNew = Documents.Add
Set tableNew = docNew.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 6, 12)

For y = 1 To 12
With tableNew
  .Cell(X, y).Range.InsertAfter Rndm * X
  End With
 For X = 1 To 6
  With tableNew
  .Cell(X, y).Range.InsertAfter Rndm * y
  End With
Next
Next

 For Each celTable In tableNew.Range.Cells
 intChar = celTable.Range.Characters.Count
  If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 1 Then
     celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
   End If
   On Error Resume Next
  If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 2 Then
     celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
     celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
   End If
  If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 3 Then
     celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
     celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 4 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 5 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 6 Then
celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 6).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 If celTable.Range.Characters.Count = 7 Then
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 1).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 3).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 4).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 5).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 6).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
 celTable.Range.Characters(intChar - 7).Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 intCount = intCount + 1

 Next celTable

End Sub
```